# AngularJS: Validation using directive (In some flavor), ngBlur or other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

In my form there is an unique input named **email**, and I want to tell if it is available in the moment of the focus is lost.

Here is the options I have studied so far:

1) Make a directive, and use `element.bind('blur', function(event)` in the link function, in that case I would inject the server to connect to the api and validate the email;

2) Make a directive, and use the `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"` in the email form, in the directive would be injected the service to validate the email as in the case 1;

3) In the form use the directive ngBlur, there I would use a function in the controller to make the validation.

Of these options what is the most standard and correct (or the angular way) to do it and why?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why bother with ngBlur if this is the only form input ? Why don't your bind you WS call to the onsubmit callback of your form ?

Comment: Use the async validation available in angular 1.3, here's an article explaining it's use: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion. Cétia, there are other fields, I just talked about the email for simplification (I over simplified it tough ), and I was think about some more reusable solution.